# v-bind:checked not working in all component instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my radio list component:

```
<template>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-hashtags" :id="'radio-hashtags-full-' + cid" value="" @change="updateHashTag" :checked="selectHashTag === ''">
        <label :for="'radio-hashtags-full-' + cid">All</label>
      </div>
      <div v-for="tag in hashTags" :key="tag" class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-hashtags" :id="'radio-hashtags-' + tag + '-' + cid" :value="tag" @change="updateHashTag" :checked="selectHashTag === tag">
        <label :for="'radio-hashtags-' + tag + '-' + cid">{{ tag }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'RadiosHashTags',
  props: ['hashTags', 'cid', 'selectHashTag'],
  methods: {
    updateHashTag (event) {
      this.$emit('updateHashTag', event.target.value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Calling this component:

```
<RadiosHashTags :hashTags="hashTags" :selectHashTag="selectHashTag" cid="1" @updateHashTag="updateHashTag"/>
```

In parent component, I just change `selectHashTag` value:

```
updateHashTag ($event) {
  this.selectHashTag = $event
},
```

If I have only one instance of this component on the page, it's works fine. But I want use it twice, in two differents components. Doing this, the `selectHashTag` is changed when i click in any instance, but check only works on the last instance.

I created a simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-almeida-8w7jy

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem changing `name` static attribute into a dynamic attribute, like that:

```
<input type="radio" :name="'radio-hashtags-' + tag + '-' + cid" :id="'radio-hashtags-' + tag + '-' + cid" :value="tag" @change="updateHashTag" :checked="selectHashTag === tag">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are emitting an event for every instance of **RadiosHashTags** and catching the same event for all values.

So, for every event emitted, the following one will subscribe the previous value. That's why you can only get the last instance.

To modify the value you just need to bind different variables and set different events to modify them.

The structure will be almost the same:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  {{ selectTag }} - {{ selectTag2 }}
    <CustomRadio :tags="tags" :selectTag="selectTag" cid="1" @updateTag="updateTag" />
    <hr>
    <CustomRadio :tags="tags" :selectTag="selectTag2" cid="2" @updateTag="updateTag2" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomRadio from "./components/CustomRadio";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    CustomRadio
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tags: ['tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3'],
      selectTag: '',
      selectTag2: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTag($event) {
      this.selectTag = $event
    },
    updateTag2($event) {
      this.selectTag2 = $event
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If you don't want to write different methods to handle the event, I highly suggest you to read about **Two Way data binding**. Using it, you'll be able to define a reactive v-model to modify the input variable without need events to handle the change.